# How can I resolve this IllegalAccessError in org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen running on Heroku?

Tags: java, javascript, heroku, rhino

I have googled far and wide and not found any references to this issue, so any help would be much appreciated.

I can regularly generate an illegal access error when using the Java Less compiler (https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java), but not on my development machine - only on Heroku (and dokku it seems - same issue there). The compiler calls compile on some javascript code, which goes through the optimiser, and fails with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.mozilla.classfile.ClassFileWriter.getLabelPC(I)I from class org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen$ExceptionManager
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen$ExceptionManager.endCatch(Codegen.java:4051)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen$ExceptionManager.removeHandler(Codegen.java:3952)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen.visitTryCatchFinally(Codegen.java:3705)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen.generateStatement(Codegen.java:1897)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen.generateStatement(Codegen.java:1873)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen.generateStatement(Codegen.java:1858)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.BodyCodegen.generateBodyCode(Codegen.java:1289)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.generateCode(Codegen.java:306)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.compileToClassFile(Codegen.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.compile(Codegen.java:75)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2377)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Context.java:1296)
    at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.init(LessCompiler.java:295)
    at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.compile(LessCompiler.java:357)
    at org.lesscss.LessCompiler.compile(LessCompiler.java:450)
```

This is particularly odd since the method it fails to call is public (https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/classfile/ClassFileWriter.java#L1260-L1268).

As mentioned, I think this has something to do with the Heroku environment, since I cannot replicate this on my development machine.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: Quick update: I suspect that there is a version conflict involved here, since the offending method is marked private in Rhino RC7.2 - I am however explicitly loading RC7.4 using leiningen (and hence maven) as my dependency manager - and it does as mention not throw this error on my development machine).

Comment: In case anyone cares about this, on my development machine the correct mozilla jar is loaded, but in the Heroku environment Rhino is loaded from `#<CodeSource (file:/app/.m2/repository/com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/r1592/closure-compiler-r1592.jar <no signer certificates>)` - next step is working out why.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by excluding the offending dependency from my build in `project.clj`, since it wasn't actually needed itself. I'm still not sure why this problem only manifested itself in some environments, but it is now resolved at least.